# How to randomly assign a web page icon?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In HTML you might do something like `link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="IMG/favicon.ico"` and your web page would have an icon. I want to know if I had multiple icons (favicon2.ico, favicon3.ico, etc.) is there a way to get the browser to randomly assign an icon from the icon files in a folder?

So one user might load the page and get favicon2 as the pages icon while another user might get favicon3, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get random Favicon using javascipt.

To achieve the result:

- Add favicons to the root of the folder('./') or any other folder (prepend path to favicon name)
- Add Id to link element like this.

`<link  id="favicon" rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon1.ico" type="image/x-icon">`

- Then add JS script to get random Favicons (Here I am replacing it for 3 favicons , for more icons simply replace 3 with number of icons)

`` <script>
    let faviconElem = document.getElementById('favicon');
faviconElem.setAttribute('href',`./favicon${Math.floor(3*Math.random())+1}.ico`);
</script> ``

**Find the attached snippet.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link  id="favicon" rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon1.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
    let faviconElem = document.getElementById('favicon');
    faviconElem.setAttribute('href',`./favicon${Math.floor(3*Math.random())+1}.ico`);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can load it dynamically by adding it with javascript when page loads:

```
let fav_num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

        let favicon = document.createElement('link');
        favicon.rel = 'icon';
        favicon.href = `IMG/favicon${fav_num}.ico`;

        document.head.appendChild(favicon);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply assign numbers to a series of desired fav-icon files in your directory. Then assign an id to the link in the document head.

The href of the fav-icon is able to be changed with js and then change it on the page load.

```
// HTML
    <link id="fav-ico" rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon-0.ico">

// JS

    let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    let favIco = document.querySelector('#fav-ico');

    favIco.href = "path/to/file/favicon-" + num + ".ico"
```